# Adding Vertical Reference in Python to ArcGIS feature dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system

I am creating a python script to generate a terrain. In the process I am creating two feature datasets. However, in order to successfully create this FD, i need both horizontal and vertical datums. I am able to code the horizontal datum successfully, but unable to input the vertical datum. Although the code does not error out, it does not create the requested feature dataset. I used the ESRI WKID's to reference horizontal and vertical datum as shown below.

Here is the code line for spatial reference that I used:

```
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(horizontal_wkid)
```

I tried doing this `sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(horizontal_wkid,vertical_wkid)` but to no avail.  I am using ESRI ArcGIS 10.2 and coding in Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the given Spatial References in ArcGIS have got their own parameters for the vertical part, as far as I know there is no way of introducing vertical part by using the given factory codes or like

> sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(horizontal_wkid,vertical_wkid)

that one may think it should work, but it is not. However, you can create your own spatial reference by borrowing necessary parameters from the given set(s). if you visit [this page](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/66715), there is an example of a similar query. In the question, you will see this definition:

```
sp=arcpy.CreateSpatialReference_management("GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],VERTCS['NAVD_1988',VDATUM['North_American_Vertical_Datum_1988'],PARAMETER['Vertical_Shift',0.0],PARAMETER['Direction',1.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]];-400 -400 1000000000;-100000 10000;-100000 10000;8.98315284119521E-09;0.001;0.001;IsHighPrecision","#","#","#","#","#","0")
```

Here the first part defines the geographic coordinate systems as:

> GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]

followed by the vertical system parameters (including name, unit, definition parameters etc.) as:

> VERTCS['NAVD_1988',VDATUM['North_American_Vertical_Datum_1988'],PARAMETER['Vertical_Shift',0.0],PARAMETER['Direction',1.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]

Then you should be able to introduce this custom spatial reference as an argument to arcpy.CreateFeatureDataset.

Comment: awesome! ill try it when i get back to the office!

Comment: What do you suggest if I had to change my coordinate system numerous times? can i insert variables into this? Please let me know! Thanks.

Comment: Has this answer resolved your problem? If so, please mark this as the answer and submit your question as a new one since it is a bit different than this one.