# Use ArcPy to set vertical coordinate system

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, toolbox

I'm trying to automate a process where a new geodatabase is created and includes a series of point feature classes that show survey points for drilled wells.

Now, I have managed to set the horizontal coordinate system and put all the data into the appropriate fields including the x,y and z coordinates, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to set the vertical datum. I need to do this so that wells with elevation values above/below sea level can be directly compared to one-another.

To set the horizontal coordinate system I have:

```
in_dataset = fc

# get the coordinate system from the proper parameter
hzCoords = parameters[13].valueAsText

# run the tool
arcpy.DefineProjection_management(in_dataset, hzCoords)
```

Where do I go from here to set the vertical datum? I'd even be happy setting the vertical datum as a standard as all the data that could possibly be used will be in the same vertical datum.

Edit: This is not a duplicate question, the answer provided in the "duplicate" doesn't work for me.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152386/adding-vertical-reference-in-python-to-arcgis-feature-dataset

Comment: When using the method from the duplicate just be careful to remember that they are using a feature dataset when you will be using a feature class.

Comment: How precisely did you try to implement the answer in the duplicate?  It is very easy to say that something does not work but we are trying to build high quality Q&A so if your question really is not a duplicate then our aim will be to improve both Q&As through the new question.  What is `hzCoords` set to in your code snippet?  Where is your `parameters` object set?  Are you perhaps using a Python toobox (`*.pyt`)?  If so, can you provide a working test toolbox/snippet that illustrates just the part where you are stuck (after trying to follow advice in the duplicate)?